# Bundle with another bundle as a dependency in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I would like to know if there's a way to create a reusable bundle that depends on a public bundle in my case, OneupFlysystemBundle ?

By adding OneupFlysystemBundle to my bundle's composer.json I can see that it's downloaded and present in the vendor folder.

I want to only include my own bundle in the AppKernel (which has a dependency on OneupFlysystemBundle)

Comment: yes it's definitely possible. did you try this https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/bundles.html ? you can add third party bundle as a dependency in composer.json of your own bundle. just look as it is done in some other third party bundles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way is to use [Symfony Flex](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html). Which allows you to use recipes. An alternative would be to use [symfony-bundle-dependencies](https://github.com/mmoreram/symfony-bundle-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

Beside these solutions I ended using the non-bundle (library) version of OneupFlysystem as a dependency of my bundle and rewrite it as facade